# Why isn't my textbox updating the CanExecute value for my WPF button command?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I am trying to learn WPF by implementing a simple button and textbox. I want to understand why my buttons `IsEnabled` state isn't updating based on the value of my text field.

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox Height="100" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         Text="{Binding Test,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         Padding="5, 3, 1, 1"
         AcceptsReturn="True" Margin="161,10,10,0"/>

<Button Content="Go" 
         IsEnabled="{Binding MyButtonCanExecute}"
         Command="{Binding MyButtomCommand}"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Margin="64,158,0,0" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

**C#:**

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool MyButtonCanExecute
    {
        get
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Test);
        }
    }

    private ICommand myButtonCommand;
    public ICommand MyButtomCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if(myButtonCommand == null)
            {
                myButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowMessage, param => this.MyButtonCanExecute);
            }
            return myButtonCommand;
        }
    }

    private string test;
    public string Test
    {
        get { return this.test; }
        set
        {
            if (this.test != value)
            {
                this.test = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Test");
            }
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        //
    }

    public void ShowMessage(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Value of textbox is set to: " + this.Test);
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. When I type into the textbox, my breakpoint in the `Test` setter does not get hit. Why? If the textbox is bound to the `Test` property, isn't that the point?
2. When I type into the textbox, the `MyButtonCanExecute` gets called constantly. However, in debug the value of `test` is always null... why? Shouldn't it take whatever I type into the textbox?

The main issue seems to be that the value of `Test` isn't updating whenever I type.

I understand there may be a different way to implementing binding the `IsEnabled` state to the length of `test`, but I want to understand what's wrong with my understanding of how WPF works.

Comment: "When I type into the textbox, my breakpoint in the Test setter does not get hit" textBox doesn't update binding for Text property immediately, unless you set UpdateSourcetrigger=PropertyChanged - by default it is LostFocus. click on button and setter should be called (assuming Window.DataContext is set properly)

Comment: @ASh Thanks, it's getting the value in the Test setter now. I added the same UpdateSourceTrigger to the IsEnabled of the button, but still it doesn't enable after typing? EDIT: Nevermind, fixed it myself. Will add an answer below and give you a mention.

Comment: IsEnabled is bound to MyButtonCanExecute, which doesn't notify when it changes. `this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Test"); this.NotifyPropertyChanged("MyButtonCanExecute");` - this will be the fix for that. But: normally you don't bind IsEnabled. IsEabled is set based on CanExecute() of bound Command - ICommand has an event to notify when CanExecute (and next IsEnabled) should be reevaluated

Comment: Yeah thanks, managed to figure that bit out. I've posted an answer in case someone else has the same issue in future. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question for future readers. Thanks for **@ASh** for pointing me in the right direction.

The problem was that, when typing into the textbox, the `UpdateSourceTrigger` had its default value (because I hadn't set it in the XAML). This meant that the property the textbox was bound to didn't update until the element lost focus, rather than when its text changed.

**The solution:**

Change the Text field of the textbox to this:

```
 Text="{Binding Test,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Note the new `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` means the source property (`MainWindowViewModel.Test`) updates every time I type.

Then, inside the Test property setting I had to add a new `NotifyPropertyChanged` call for the `MyButtonCanExecute` property which is dependent on the value of `Test`:

```
    private string test;
    public string Test
    {
        get { return this.test; }
        set
        {
            if (this.test != value)
            {
                this.test = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Test");
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("MyButtonCanExecute");
            }
        }
    }
```

And also add the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to the `IsEnabled` value of the button:

```
 <Button Content="Go" 
      IsEnabled="{Binding MyButtonCanExecute,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      Command="{Binding MyButtomCommand}" />
```

**EDIT:** 
A better solution is to remove the IsEnabled binding altogether, so you just have:

```
 <Button Content="Go" 
      Command="{Binding MyButtomCommand}" />
```

This is because when we create the `MyButtonCommand` we pass in `MyButtonCanExecute` as the `CanExecute` property to the `RelayCommand`:

```
 myButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowMessage, param => this.MyButtonCanExecute);
```